# Oracle not available 11g R2

Tags: oracle11g

I had one environment installed Oracle 11g R2 for few months, it was working well for past few months, but this week, I got error when I connect.

My environment:
Windows 7 64 bit with SP1

So I trying to investigate:

Here is my listener.ora

```
    # listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
    SID_LIST_LISTENER =
      (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
        )
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = orcl)
          (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
          (GLOBAL_DBNAME=orcl)
        )
      )
    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC))
          )
          (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.1.100.134)(PORT = 1521))
          )
        )
      )

    ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log
```

and my tnsnames.ora

```
    # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

    ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = CLRExtProc)
          (PRESENTATION = RO)
        )
      )

    ORCL =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.1.100.134)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
          (GLOBAL_NAME = orcl)
        )
      )
```

Here is my investigate process:

1. using LSNRCTL to check listener status(sorry I translate from Chinese to English)

```
    LSNRCTL> status
    Connect to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC)))
    Listener status
    ------------------------
    Alias                    LISTENER
    Version                  TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Start Date               24-12-2014 11:13:04
    Normal operation Time    0 day 0 hour 21 minute 32 second
    Trace Level              off
    Security                 ON: Local OS Authentication
    SNMP                     OFF
    Listener config file     D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
    Listener log file        d:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log\diag\tnslsnr\1300313-PC\listener\alert\log.xml
    Listener summary...
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROCipc)))
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.1.100.134)(PORT=1521)))
    Service Summary...
    service "PLSExtProc" has 1 execute process.
      execute process "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler for this service...
    service "orcl" has 1 execute process.
      execute process "orcl", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler for this service...
    command complete
```

2. Using TNSPING

```
    D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>tnsping orcl

    TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 24-12-2014 11:39:23

    Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

    Config file:
    D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

    Using TNSNAMES adaptor to parse alias
    try connecting (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.1.100.134)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orcl) (GLOBAL_NAME = orcl)))
    OK (40 msec)
```

3. Using SQLPLUS

```
    D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>sqlplus / as sysdba

    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wednesday 12.24 11:43:17 2014
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    Connect to idle execution process.
    SQL> startup
    ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
    ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_ORCL'
    SQL> exit
    disconnected

    D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl
    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wednesday 12.24 11:44:01 2014
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    ERROR:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
    ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
    Process ID: 0
    Session ID: 0 Sequence: 0
```

my environment variable as

```
    D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>echo %ORACLE_HOME%
    D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
    D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>echo %ORACLE_SID%
    orcl
```

Appreciated if any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found wired thing, that oracle init config missing. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, please mark you answer as "accepted anwser".